# Join two mysql tables with Where Cluase

Tags: mysql, database

I need to join MySQL tables.
but when I apply where clause on the second table, query return no record.
I want a query that returns all records of the 1st table and joins with 2nd table data on certain conditions and if the condition does not find records in the second table then it appends null in the result.

Please see the attached picture for detail.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnHrm.png)

```
SELECT *
FROM `Table1` 
JOIN `Table2` ON `Table1`.`id1` = `Table2`.`id2`
WHERE `Table2`.`department_id` = 2;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a left join, and move the where criteria to the join condition:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.id1 = t2.id2 AND t2.department_id = 2;
```